# Condition Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am writing a code that can validate if a condition is correct or not. A condition is an expression which results in `true` or `false`.

for example: `X+Y>Z` is a valid condition. `X+Y` is not.

And then, there can be complex conditions like `( X + Y > Z ) && ( X - Y < Z )` which is also correct. But `( X + Y > Z) && Z` is not. These conditions can be as complex as then need to be. I used javascript eval() function to validate those conditions. Here is my code:

```
try{
    var evaled=eval(expression);
    if(evaled===true||evaled===false) alert("Valid.");
    else alert("Invalid");
}catch(err){
    // eval throws exception on syntax error
    alert("Invalid. Syntax error.");
}
```

This works well for most of things but results valid in cases like this : `( X > Y) && Z` which should be invalidated. Also, expression like this `X + Z && (X>Z)` is also showing valid.  How can I make this validation correct.

Comment: So where is the problem? Are you expecting someone to write you a different implementation of eval?

Comment: `( X > Y) && Z which should be invalidated`. Why?

Comment: @dfsq I'm assuming that's how OP wants it to work.

Comment: @dfsq because Z is not a valid condition itself. When I am using && or ||, both sides should have a condition.

Comment: JavaScript will definitely give you a success if the expression is successfully parsed. The problem you are facing is that your definition of "valid/invalid" is different from JavaScript's. If I were you, I may want to list all possible conditions where valid or not can be determined. If all conditions are limited, a (rather) simple Regex pattern will do it right for you. If not, then Regex may not help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my question. 
I created a way of signaturing all the conditions.

For all the operands in the condition, I placed `x` in the signature, 
for all arithmetic operators, i placed an `o`, 
for logical operators `l`, 
for relational operators `t`, 
for not operator `n`.

Then I kept replacing `xox` with `x` until there are no arithmetic operators, then I replaced all `xtx` with `c`, `c` is for condition. then I replaced `nc` and `clc` with `c`.

In the end, if the signature results in a single `c`, its a valid condition, else its not.

here is my code :

```
            while(exp.indexOf("xox")!=-1||exp.indexOf("(x)")!=-1){
                exp=exp.replace("xox","x");
                exp=exp.replace("(x)", "x");
            }

            while(exp.indexOf("xtx")!=-1||exp.indexOf("(c)")!=-1){
                exp=exp.replace("xtx","c");
                exp=exp.replace("(c)", "c");
            }


            while(exp.indexOf("clc")!=-1||exp.indexOf("(c)")!=-1||exp.indexOf("nc")!=-1){
                exp=exp.replace("clc","c");
                exp=exp.replace("(c)", "c");
                exp=exp.replace("nc", "c");
            }
            if(exp==c){
                 return true;
            }else return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval` will give you the result according to currently defined variables, and according to JavaScript boolean rules, in which all values are either truthy and falsy, and thus permissible arguments for `&&`, `||` and `!`. I.e. `true || ("foo" + 1)` is a valid expression in JavaScript, and will evaluate to `true` - as will `"moo" && X < 3` if `X` is `1`.

If you want to check things according to your own grammar, you can't use `eval`, and you will have to implement your own parser (possibly using a parser generator such as [Jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/))

EDIT: thanks for sharp eyes, Nateowami.

Comment: There's no logic bug. If it evaluates to false it still counts it as valid. Only if an exception is thrown will it execute `alert("Invalid. Syntax error.")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `constructor === Boolean`

```
console.log(eval("1+2").constructor === Boolean); //false
console.log(eval("1+2 > 1").constructor === Boolean); //true
console.log(eval("true").constructor === Boolean); //true
console.log(eval("false").constructor === Boolean); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue Amadan thoughts, in your conditions if Z is defined so it will return `true` and if X are higher then Y so `( X > Y ) && Z` goona be true and `X + Z` gonna be true if X and Z are defined values.
You can try `Boolean(your expression)` to see what it gonna be.